# New WebApi Project doesn't have default routing for API (but still works)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've created a new WebAPI MVC project, the API controllers have the path `http://localhost:1234/api` and they work from this route, but the `RegisterRoutes` class doesn't contain a default routing, it contains the following:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Where's the routing for the API?

Cheers

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Visual Studio project templates creates a default route which looks like:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "API Default",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

You can find this in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file, which is placed in the `App_Start` directory

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: I didn't see that you'd actually written which class it was in or I would have marked it as correct sooner.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

It lives in a different class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace HelloWorldApi
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
            // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
            // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
            //config.EnableQuerySupport();

            // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
            // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }
    }
}
```